# Error when adding/updating keychain value with kSecClass

Tags: swift, keychain

I'm trying to add/update a keychain value using the dictionary below:

```
public var itemDictionary: [String: Any] {
  let dictionary: [CFString: Any?] = [
    kSecAttrAccessGroup: accessGroup, // nil
    kSecAttrService: service, // nil
    kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
    kSecAttrAccount: account,
    kSecAttrSynchronizable: synchronizable, // false
    kSecAttrAccessible: access.queryValue,
    kSecValueData: data
  ]
  return dictionary.compactMapValues { $0 } as [String: Any]
}
```

However, both `SecItemAdd` and `SecItemUpdate` fail with an error of -25303 (`errSecNoSuchAttr`). After some debugging, I figured out that if I removed `kSecClass` from the dictionary above, that both `SecItemAdd` and `SecItemUpdate` work as expected. This doesn't seem right though as my understanding is that `kSecClass` is a required field. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `-25303` indicates `errSecNoSuchAttr`. So you are either trying to add an attribute that is not supported by a generic password (which it appears you don't), so it might be a value you're trying to set. Also, try checking out the message for the status you're getting using `SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil)`, maybe that'll show you what key is invalid

Comment: SecCopyErrorMessageString just said "The specified attribute does not exist." and didn't give any more info :(

Comment: Can you add more info as to what you are adding as values to each specified attribute? Also, have you tried eliminating keys by removing one at a time to see if the query then succeeds?

Comment: I can show the account or data, but the accessible value is kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock. It works fine if I remove kSecClass.

Comment: I can't show the account or data**